# Which wordpress function is the caption shortcode linked to?

Tags: shortcode, customization

I have used this code in my page content to try and output an image + caption with a custom caption class and id...

`[caption id="my-caption-id" class="my-caption-class" align="alignnone" width="399"]<img src="whatever.jpg" alt="whatever" width="399" height="600" /> My caption text[/caption]`

...but the caption's id and class names are not being output.

After some digging around, I found the `img_caption_shortcode` function in wp-includes/media.php which handles the id and class attributes of the `[caption]` shortcode but, after some experimenting, it seems this function is not executed with the `[caption]` shortcode...

So does anyone know which function the `[caption]` shortcode is linked to? (and / or how to get the class and id attributes to be output on a caption?)

I'm using WordPress 3.9.2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this on a default theme (without any plugins), to see if that makes any difference.

Your shortcode example:

```
[caption id="my-caption-id" class="my-caption-class" align="alignnone" width="399"]
    <img src="whatever.jpg" alt="whatever" width="399" height="600" /> 
    My caption text
[/caption]
```

gives this output:

```
<div id="my-caption-id" 
     style="width: 409px" 
     class="wp-caption alignnone my-caption-class">
    <img src="whatever.jpg" alt="whatever" width="399" height="600">
    <p class="wp-caption-text">My caption text</p>
</div>
```

on the *Twenty Twelve* theme. It's just a little bit formatted to make it easier to read here.

So the *caption id* and *classes* are displayed in the output.

### Update:

It looks like your theme is overriding the image caption via:

```
// Remove default inline style of wp-caption
add_shortcode('wp_caption', 'fixed_img_caption_shortcode');
add_shortcode('caption', 'fixed_img_caption_shortcode');
```

in the [`/library/cleanup.php`](https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress/blob/master/library/cleanup.php) file.

Comment: Of course. Thank you. I am using the FoundationPress theme. I'm pretty sure that will be overriding the shortcode function.

Comment: I think I found the overriding image caption code within your theme. Please check out the updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I've just submitted a Pull Request that corrects this - https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress/pull/98